# Bluetooth LE Characteristic Write Response

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have an embedded device running BT5 with GATT server setup. On the server I have setup a service with various characteristics to allow a client (PC or Mobile Device) to adjust various parameters of the device by writing to the characteristics.

I would like, for the device to send a response back from the application level for each write. It's not clear to me what the recommended way would be.

I thought about having the client read or subscribe to a general status characteristic, but I want to make sure I am not missing an easier way to do this. I looked at the BT write with response command, but it seems the acknowledgement for that may happen lower than the application.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Write Response as "application level response". I have not seen any Bluetooth stack where this response is sent at a lower level before the application has processed the request. The reason is probably because the application can even send an Application Error code instead of a Write Response, so it would be stupid to move the Write Response handling to a lower level. Even in Android (if you set up a GATT server) you send the Write Response from the application.

The situation is different with Indications, though, where the Bluetooth stack sometimes sends the Confirmation at a lower level than the application, before it even informs the application that an Indication has arrived, which I find a bit strange and makes Indications kind of pointless compared to Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a Notification characteristic. The client first subscribes to notification events on that CCD, and then every command sent to the host/device is acknowledged by the host firing the notification. To better synchronize command-and-response, you could add an incremental command-id with every command, and have the command-id be part of the notification data that is sent back to the client.

However I implemented this because I needed a response *after* the device has processed the command, with the results sent back to the client. If all you want to know is whether or not the host has received the command, a Write-With-Response CCD is the way to go.

> I looked at the BT write with response command, but it seems the acknowledgement for that may happen lower than the application.

Indeed, the Write-With-Response-Handler is almost always implemented on the BLE stack, not on application level. However I don't see why this would be a problem; you should get error reports by your BLE stack in some form when a Write-with-Response fails. If it's a blocking call it might even return a success-value.